# If a listbox contains an item LIKE

Tags: vb.net

Is there anywhere to check whether a listbox contains an item which is similar to a string?

I have tried to use a Like statement but this doesn't work.

I have tried:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To TopicListBox.Items.Count - 1
                If (TopicListBox.Items(i).ToString.Contains(Record.Item("Keyphrase2"))) Then
                    Dim Item As String = TopicListBox.Items(i).ToString
                    If Item Like "Questions related to:" & Record.Item("Keyphrase2") & ": |*| Qs" Then
                        Dim ItemSplit() As String = Item.Split(New Char() {"|"c})
                        Dim AmountOfQuestionsAfter As Integer = AmountOfQuestions + CInt(ItemSplit(1))
                        Item = ItemSplit(0) & AmountOfQuestionsAfter & ItemSplit(1)
                    Else
                        TopicListBox.Items.Add("Questions related to:" & Record.Item("Keyphrase2") & ": |" & AmountOfQuestions & "| Qs")
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: Check out `string.contains` method

Comment: Yes but this doesn't allow making Like comparisons

Comment: Iterate through all items in a ListBox in a loop and do a `Like` against each? Save your matches as you go...

Comment: @user2177940 Have you looked at it? It *is* a Like comparasion.

Comment: What do you mean? Provide an example of what you are trying to do instead of letting us guess. What is an item SIMILAR to a string???

Comment: What are you trying to do? Use English words, please. Inferring that from code can be different and at times pointless. Define `does not work`. What is your code supposed to do? Where does it deviate from your planned execution? Did you try debugging at all? Like operator [syntax is described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx).

Comment: Its looking to see whether a keyphrase is in a listbox of items. It iterates through all the items to see whether any of the items contains this keyword. If it does, then it should add a number to an integer in this listbox which is located using the split function.

Comment: I am planning on doing this twice with 2 sets of keywords in a database.

Comment: @user2177940: Always use `@` + user name, when replying, otherwise I don't get notified of your replies. So are you trying to change a ListBox based on its own contents?

Comment: @Neolisk Yes that's basically the idea of it.

Comment: This is a bad idea, never change the contents of a collection when you are iterating through it. Needs to be a different ListBox, or accumulate changes and update after the loop, by iterating through your change list.

Comment: Even though you explained it a bit, I am still not quite clear on what you want. Please include a screenshot of "before" and "after". I think there exists a more simple and readable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish, but here is a LINQ function to return all the items that contain a certain string.

```
Dim lb As New ListBox

lb.Items.Add("asdf")
lb.Items.Add("asdfasdf")
lb.Items.Add("aifisasdf")
lb.Items.Add("adf")

'' find all items in the ListBox that contain the string "asdf"
Dim found = lb.Items.Cast(Of String).Where(Function(f) f.Contains("asdf"))

For Each s In found
  '' do something with those items
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do

```
If Item.Contains("Questions related to:" & Record.Item("Keyphrase2")) Then
    ...
End If
```

or

```
If Item.StartsWith("Questions related to:" & Record.Item("Keyphrase2")) Then
    ...
End If
```

?

Comment: @user2177940 no, believe me, they work... you're doing something wrong. Debug and check the value of that Item string

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Found = (From Result In lb.Items Where Result.ToString = "Value" Select Result)

If (Found.Count > 0) Then
    ' your code
End If
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.